# Automatically detect box/coordinates of burned-in subtitles in a video source

Tags: video, ffmpeg, subtitle, video-subtitles

In reality I'd like to detect the coordinates of the "biggest" (both in height and width) burned-in subtitle of a given video source. But in order to do this I first need to detect the box coordinates of every distinct subtitle in the sample video, and compare them to find the biggest one. I didn't know where to start about this, so the closest thing I found (sort of) was ffmpeg's `bbox` video filter which according to the documentation computes `"the bounding box for the non-black pixels in the input frame luminance plane"`, based on a given luminance value:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf bbox=min_val=130 -f null -
```

This gives me a line with coordinates for each input frame in the video, ex.:

```
[Parsed_bbox_0 @ 0ab734c0] n:123 pts:62976 pts_time:4.1 x1:173 x2:1106 y1:74 y2:694 w:934 h:621 crop=934:621:173:74 drawbox=173:74:934:621
```

The idea was to make a script and loop through the filter's output, detect the "biggest" box by comparing them all, and output its coordinates and frame number as representative of the longest subtitle.

The `bbox` filter though can't properly detect the subtitle box even in a relatively dark video with white hardsubs. By trial and error and only for a particular video sample which I used to run my tests, the "best" result for detecting the box of any subtitle was to use a `min_val` of 130 (supposedly the meaningful values of `min_val` are in the range of 0-255, although the docs don't say anything). Using the `drawbox` filter with `ffplay` to test the coordinates reported for a particular frame, I can see that it correctly detects only the bottom/left/right boundary of the subtitle, presumably because the outline of the globe in the image below is equally bright:

[image]

Raising `min_val` to 230 slightly breaks the previously correct boundaries at the bottom/left/right side:

[image]

And raising it to 240 gives me a weird result:

[image]

However even if I was able to achieve a perfect outcome with the `bbox` filter, this technique wouldn't be bulletproof for obvious reasons (the `min_val` should be arbitrarily chosen, the burned-in subtitles can be of different color, the image behind the subtitles can be equally or even more bright depending the video source, etc.).

So if possible I would like to know:

1. Is there a filter or another technique I can use with ffmpeg to do what I want
2. Is there perhaps another CLI tool or programming library to achieve this
3. Any hint that could help (perhaps I'm looking at the problem the wrong way)